# "Ingenious guessing" and "devinettes ingénieuses"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

> Book III concerns the "System of the World, that is, the sun, the
>   planets and their moons, and certain comets. In it Newton attempted to
>   show that his law of universal gravitation sufficed to explain in
>   detail the phenomena of celestial mechanics. Since the mathematical
>   structure presented in Book I was insufficient to treat a universe
>   containing more than two bodies, Newton had to resort here to
>   approximations of various sorts.
>   **Here, too, he showed himself a consummate master of mathematics and of ingenious guessing.**
>   (Clifford Truesdell 1968).

I am puzzled of how rendering in French the sentence in bold.

Google translate gives:

> Là aussi, il se montra un maître accompli en mathématiques et en
>   devinettes ingénieuses.

DeepL gives a similar interpretation.

But I am wondering if devinette renders correctly the sense of guessing in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rapporté à ce que Newton a fait, je traduirais sans la moindre hésitation *guessing* par **conjecture**.

C'est peut-être pour *ingenious* que j'hésiterais entre :

- **astucieuse** (il a fait quelques approximations)
- **judicieuse** (bien vues)

Après... dans un bouquin tout public... je changerais certainement *conjecture astucieuse* par... *intuition*.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same hesitation and it starts with the original (guessing), which I find rather wanting in the light of the intellectual task considered. That's why, even though a little infringement with respect to the obligation to remain faithful to the author's words, a translation such as the following, it seems to me, would put the context back, at least as far as the French point of view goes, into a more exact perspective.

> Là aussi, il se montra un maître accompli en mathématiques et dans l'art de la spéculation scientifique.